# How to stretch tr cells evenly in a table?

Tags: html, css

Good day. I have a table with these styles. And I'm trying to stretch the table on the screen, even if there are few columns (3 - 2 pieces). How can I make tr blocks stretch evenly. When I try to set tr to 100% width, only the first column is stretched. And I need the blocks to have the same width when stretching a small number of columns to fill the screen. At the same time, I cannot know in advance how many columns there will be.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

tbody,
th,
thead {
  display: block;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 8px 60px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

thead {
  float: left;
  background: #ae6363;
}

tbody {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

tbody tr {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  /*? here ?*/
  width: 100%;
}

tbody td {
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  background: #ae6333;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: are you looking for an exact solution with that style only? are you against using grid template and `grid-template-columns`? I ask because it's quite odd that you used table rows as column forcing their display as `table-cell`. I tried styling their apparent width by even stating the `table-layout: fixed`  but the value must be fine tuned on the expected total width with inconsistent results. I'm afraid it could just bring to unexpected results because a table row is not expected to be like that. But the `grid` layout would surely fulfill that scenario and preserving semantics also

Comment: It was my attempt to display the table in such a given form. If there is another way to display the table, which will lead to this view, I will be glad if you tell me how to do it. And most importantly, in the end, this solved my problem described in the question, if this is of course even possible. @Diego D

Comment: If you don't have javascript you could create CSS classes for every number of columns and set the percentage width accordingly. Also you wrote about "tr cells" and pointed to the tr CSS? The cells are the `td`. Or do you mean space the rows at an even height?

Comment: I have to withdraw my words. It seems the grid layout is not good at keeping the semantics and anyway requires some stretches to get to that same result. As well I never considered how to show tabular data showing rows as column and viceversa. I'm taking for granted that the number of cols is unknown on the style so it can't structure the tabular layout in a semantic way pushing also the rows layout. The table remains superior but at the same time I don't know how to reverse rows and cols. Unfortunately I couldn't be of help

Comment: Why are you making a tr render as a table cell? Why don't you give each cell a fixed % width?